# World of Tanks - spotting questions

Tags: world-of-tanks

1. What part of a tank is spotting done from?  The entire tank or just the turret?  Does poking the front of your tank out around a rock spot things beyond it or do you have to drive far enough forward so that your turret is exposed?
2. When two tanks are both in spotting distance to one another, do they both spot each other simultaneously?  This is considering that there is no bushes in the way.  For example, when you are peeking around a rock at another rock when an enemy tank comes around it.

Comment: You should summarize your question in the title. And you can open two different questions if you need, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered on the [WOT wiki](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/View_Range_%26_Camouflage_%28WoT%29).

In short:

1. Several location are evaluated, at a different rate depending on the distance you are. Top of turret, Front, tracks are all evaluated.
2. No. The camouflage mechanism makes it asymmetric. It may be true for the same tank, same crew level and camo paint/net applied.